# Joomla installation magic quotes issue

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, magic-quotes-gpc

The latest Joomla 3.0 will need magic quotes to turn off in order to start the installation.

As usual, i turn it off using php.ini created inside the sub folder where my joomla files are inside.

in my phpinfo, magic_quotes_gpc is writing Off. but in my joomla installation page, magic quotes still showing "No".

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Usually editing the php.ini requires the restart of the server to work.

Have a look at the PHP function [`get_magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php). There may be no issue with Joomla after all.

Comment: i am using shared hosting. what i am trying to do is to create a php.ini in my root folder. and i don't think i can reset the server. after created the php.ini and adding magic_quotes_gpc Off line, in my phpinfo it shows magic_quotes_gpc is writing Off, but still wondering why my joomla installation magic quotes still showing "No".

Answer (score 0):

No way of solving it with a php.ini file. It'll "seem to work" but doesn't. You need to set magic_quotes_gpc = off on the server php configuration.

Comment: base from joomla forum, most of them using this method to solve this issue.

Comment: magic_quotes_gpc is a deprecated function since PHP 5.3.0 and will be removed in PHP 5.4.0. As you may check, the magic_quotes_gpc directive may only be disabled at the system level, and not at runtime. (http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php). Hope it helps